# How to play store handle updates with compatible android devices?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have  updated my app according to google policy requirements as following.
Apps must comply with the Target API policy (apps must target API 31 or newer to stay available and API 33 to submit).
New Release is working fine in New devices which have new android versions.

but  the  users who have older android versions also get this update into their phones .
Then those users complained to me that the application crashed on their devices .
That is the problem .

I don't know how the play store handles this ?
(if there are 2 releases active in play store App bundle explorer , play store automatically detect and  show relevant app to the devices  etc)

there is no options to disable/enable releases in app bundle explorer also.
How  enable my  app to the  users who have older  versions of android ?

Answer (score 0):

If you app requires a minimum specific Android version to run, then you should set minSdkVersion to the minimum supported API level. Play store will not offer the app to devices that are running an older version of Android.